# Where to put global custom ansible filters

Tags: ansible

I have a project with collections and roles. The collections and roles have custom filters and modules. I know where to create modules / filters in a role or collection.

Is it possible to have global filters? Where can I put these?

The structure of my project is

```
├── ansible_collections
│   ├── ...
├── group_vars
│   └── ...
├── host_vars
│   └── ...
├── plays
│   └── ..
├── roles
│   ├── external
│   └── internal
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put `filter_plugins` in `ansible.cfg` for example

```
# set plugin path directories here, separate with colons
#action_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/action
#become_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/become
#cache_plugins      = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/cache
#callback_plugins   = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/callback
#connection_plugins = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/connection
#lookup_plugins     = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/lookup
#inventory_plugins  = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/inventory
#vars_plugins       = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/vars
filter_plugins      = filter_plugins
#test_plugins       = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/test
#terminal_plugins   = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/terminal
#strategy_plugins   = /usr/share/ansible/plugins/strategy
```